# How do I tell GRUB to ignore other bootloaders?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, grub-efi

I want to keep my bootloaders separately and I am wondering how to tell GRUB not to add the Windows bootloader on kernel/grub updates. I am using 14.04 and Win 8.1 on UEFI.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality of GRUB is called the OS Prober.

There are a couple options you can try:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and find this line, set it to `true`:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Or you can change the os-prober file so that it isn't used:

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

Both methods from this thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1529799